# determining correspondance between linked library version and conda version

Tags: shared-libraries, conda, miniconda

I cannot see any obvious correspondance. If I need a particular version, how do I pick it?

I ran some software called [Dorado](https://github.com/nanoporetech/dorado), and it complained that it required `libhdf5.so.8`, despite the fact that I had `conda install`-ed `hd5` (the package that provides libhdf5). I was running dorado in a conda environment, so naturally I ran `conda info --envs` found the path to my conda environment, and looked around. I found that I had `libhdf5.so.10` : not version 8. Listing versions with `conda search hdf5` did not tell me which was which, and in fact the earliest version I could install with conda was version 10.

Comment: But `dorado` itself is not a Conda package, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error shows you can get it with `hdf5=1.8.13` which is only available on the **free** channel in Conda:

```bash
## always use dedicated environment when installing legacy versions
conda create -n dorado free::hdf5=1.8.13
```

Don't expect this to be compatible with contemporary Conda packages that use `libhdf5`.